# C# - Is there any way to do some work when a variable gets assigned to another variable (copy constructor?)

Tags: c#, variables, object

```
var abc = new MyObject();
var xyz = abc;
```

As I understand it, xyz and abc are distinct objects pointing to the same information.

Is there a way I can do ref counting? Basically, I want to increment a value inside the object, when an assignment happens

Comment: Why would you care how many references there are to your object? Maybe if we know that we can cook a different solution.

Comment: ref counting is a possible solution to a number of problems, but not one that is easy/possible in C#. If you could describe the problem you're trying to solve, you may get better answers.

Comment: @Cosmin Prund Ref counting can be useful for the implementation of lazy copy schemes with value semantics. If you abc object points to some big reference, you dont want to copy it really, when doing 'xyz = abc'. Only, when altering xyz a copy is necessary - and only, if abc is not using the resource anymore.

Answer (score 2):

No. C# is not C++; the value isn't actually copied in the code snippet you pasted (unless `MyObject` is a value type).

Comment: I know that, that's why I'm asking. So you're saying, it positively cannot be done?

Answer (score 2):

No, `xyz` and `abc` are distinct *references* to the *same* object.

And no, you cannot do reference counting.

Answer (score 1):

The only way of doing this is by utilizing (implicit) cast operator overloads. Probably this is not, what was intended by Eric et.all, but it works if you design your classes carefully for it.

In the overloaded operator, you can create the new (left side) object and update any reference counters. However, it is clear, this implies to make sure, no other ways exists around that scheme. I.e. the object on the right side *must* always be of the correct type. And the use of 'var' would be completely impossible.

Comment: And how do you propose to decrement the reference counter?

Comment: @ChrisWue Naive solution would be: via finalizers. Better: by tracking the livetime of all objects and implement some scoping. This can be done by careful use of 'using ()' blocks, for example. I dont claim this to be an easy solution. But it can be helpful though.

Comment: Mh, well that only helps if you want to count assignments essentially. If you want to keep track of the current ref count then you are kinda lost.

Comment: Commonly, the reference counter gets increased due to assignments?

Comment: Yeah, what I mean is that you cannot decrement references. Example `var a = new MyObject(); var b = a;` You can increment the counter but assuming `b` is a local variable living only till the end of the function you cannot automatically decrement the counter.

Comment: @ChrisWue you are right, the livetime of objects (and deterministic diposal) is hard to determine. However, by introducing some scoping rules, a special class design and strictly utilizing using blocks, one can simulate a dispose-when-out-of-scope behavior.

Answer (score 0):

C# doesn't allow the overloading of the assignment operator. You could use wrappers that increment/decrement the reference count, but that's not as pretty. Here's a rough sketch:

```
class RefCounted<T>
{
    private int refCount;
    public readonly T Obj;

    public RefCounted(T obj)
    {
        Obj = obj;
    }

    public void Get()
    {
        refCount++;
    }

    public void Release()
    {
        if (refCount > 0)
        {
            refCount--;
        }
    }
}

class Wrapper<T> : IDisposable
{
    private RefCounted<T> obj;
    private bool disposed = false;

    public Wrapper(RefCounted<T> o)
    {
        o.Get();
        obj = o;
    }

    public Wrapper<T> Copy()
    {
        return new Wrapper<T>(obj);
    }

    public static implicit operator T(Wrapper<T> wrapper)
    {
        return wrapper.obj.Obj;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                obj.Release();
                obj = null;
            }
            disposed = true;
        }
    }
}

static class Wrapper
{
    public static Wrapper<T> New<T>(T obj)
    {
        return new Wrapper<T>(new RefCounted<T>(obj));
    }
}
```

Here's an example:

```
public class Task
{
    public int TaskId { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
}

...

var o = Wrapper.New(new Task() { TaskId = 1 });
var o1 = o.Copy();
var o2 = o1.Copy();
((Task) o1).TaskId = 3;
o2.Dispose();
o1.Dispose();
o.Dispose();
```

You can also use `using` for scoping since the wrapper implements `IDisposable`.